# Full coordinates database - multilanguage

Tags: database, coordinates, multilingual, country, city

I'm looking for a full multilanguage database with  country - state - city - coordinate.

I found some databases but they are all in English.

Do you have some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

[IP2Location](http://ip2location.com/free/city-multilingual) has multilingual city database but they only provide this for their customer.